# ruby on rails tutorial 2.5 exercise - Application Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm in the Rails Tutorial working on the exercises at the end of Chapter 2 and I'm stumped. www.railstutorial.org/book/toy_app#sec-toy_app_exercises

The code in Listing 2.18 shows how to add a validation for the presence of micropost content in order to ensure that microposts can’t be blank. **Verify that you get the behavior shown in Figure 2.19.**

I could find pretty similar questions but none told me about verifying the changes.
**IN OTHER WORDS - how do I save the changes I'm making, so I could see them in the actual web page?**

I've tried-

```
$ git status
$ git add -A
$ git commit -m "Finish toy app"
$ git push
```

and then-

```
$ git push heroku
```

and then

```
$ heroku run rake db:migrate
```

and the page broke, giving me the message

> Application Error An error occurred in the application and your page
>   could not be served. Please try again in a few moments.
>
> If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.

was I doing the right actions or should I do something else in order to save changes and deploy them?

pls excuse me for being a noob,and thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it! after an hour of search, my problem was a stupid syntax mistake - I forgot to add a "," sign after one of the code lines in micropost.rb

sorry for troubling and thanks for the assistance